# Sanitizing data PHP - do i need to escape user inputs that are inside if statements?

Tags: php, if-statement, sanitization

I'm sanitizing all user inputs that are output on page, e.g.:

```
echo escape($user_input);
```

I have a question about user inputs that are not output to the page but are inside statements - do they need escaped?

Is this OK:

```
if ($user_input == 'something') { echo escape($another_user_input); }
```

or should it be:

```
if (escape($user_input) == 'something') { echo escape($another_user_input); }
```

Same question for other logic (foreach loops etc.) which would add more faff than this simple example.

Comment: The second one before inserting into the database so the value is cleared from any bad codes. Example, usernames! and the first one is for something like a comment, you take the user's input and print it escaped and use htmlspecialchars!

Comment: @MrPro Wut?! Why?

Comment: in the case where you are only comparing them to a predefined string, there's little use in escaping the input. the `echo` line should be escaped, and you should make sure there is nothing in there that could ruin the HTML in your page or insert a malicious script, so in that case, i think just `escape` is not enough.

Comment: There is no need for "sanitization" when you output data. But there is a big requirement for proper formatting the data using the rules of the language of the generated output (HTML, JavaScript, SQL etc).

Comment: Just to clarify: obviously not all comparisons will be predefined strings - 'something' could be any logic here. Escape is my sanitization function - so please assume it's good for sanitizing HTML for output. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason you ever need to escape something is when you're interpolating data into another text medium which gets re-interpreted according to some rules.

E.g.:

```
echo '<p>' . $somedata . '</p>';
```

This is programmatically generating HTML which will get interpreted by an HTML parser and will have specific behaviour depending on what's inside `$somedata`.

```
$query = 'SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = ' . $somedata;
```

This is programmatically generating an SQL query which will get interpreted by an SQL parser and will have specific behaviour depending on what's inside `$somedata`.

If you want to ensure that HTML or that query behaves as you intended, you better make sure you generate those textual commands in a way does that not allow anyone to inject unwanted commands.

```
if ($somedata == 'something')
```

Here you're not creating some new text which will be interpreted by something. There's no way for anyone to inject anything here. It's not like PHP is replacing `$somedata` with the contents of `$somedata` and then re-interprets that line with the interpolated data. So there's no need to escape this in any way.

Also see [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and really useful article - it has helped to more fully understand the issues.